# Automate uploading users image to Active Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a code that finds all AD users and compares them to our photo folder. If they arent a user the image is archived, if it is found then nothing happens. What I want to do is if the user exists and the thumbnail attribute is empty, then upload the image to the thumbnail. This has proven to be harder than expected. Any idea of how to mass upload images?
My code currently is

```
$usersWithoutImage = Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties thumbnailPhoto | ? {(-not($_.thumbnailPhoto))} 
| select Name
$repPics = (Get-childItem \\web01\rep-pics).basename

ForEach ($image in $usersWithoutImage){
    if ($usersWithoutImage -eq $repPics){
        $ADphoto = [byte[]](Get-Content $image -Encoding byte)
        Set-ADUser $repPics -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$ADphoto}

}
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Nothing uploads to Active Directory. No error occurs, the image just doesnt show up in AD's attribute as a hex code.

Answer (score 0):

Step one is to add some logging so you know if and when certain branches of code are hit.

```
$repPics = (Get-childItem \\web01\rep-pics).basename
Write-host "Found $($usersWithoutImage.Count) users without a photo"
ForEach ($image in $usersWithoutImage){
    if ($usersWithoutImage -eq $repPics){
        Write-host "Users name [$image] is in the users photo directory, uploading..."
        $ADphoto = [byte[]](Get-Content $image -Encoding byte)
        Set-ADUser $repPics -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$ADphoto}
    }
    else{
        Write-Warning "Users name [$image] is NOT in the users photo directory, please update!!"
    }
}
```

Doing some analysis of your code reveals this line...

```
    if ($usersWithoutImage -eq $repPics){
```

Which will never evaluate to true because the comparison doesn't make sense.  You should check to see if the current user is `-in` the array of `$repPics`, not if it `-equals`, because that will never be the case.  I'd rewrite it like this:

```
ForEach ($user in $usersWithoutImage){
    if ($repPics -contains $user){
```

So your completed code would look like this:

```
$repPics = (Get-childItem \\web01\rep-pics).basename
Write-host "Found $($usersWithoutImage.Count) users without a photo"
ForEach ($user in $usersWithoutImage){
    if ($repPics -contains $user){
        Write-host "Users name [$user] is in the users photo directory, uploading..."
        $imagePath = ".\$($user).png"
        $ADphoto = [byte[]](Get-Content $imagePath -Encoding byte)
        Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$ADphoto}
    }
    else{
        Write-Warning "Users name [$user] is NOT in the users photo directory, please update!!"
    }
}
```

One last thing is that you need to update line `$imagePath =...` to match your file path and file type.

Comment: I will work a bit with this to see if I can make it work. At the moment I am getting every image as not in the directory. Thanks for the insight on this problem!

Comment: Change the line `$imagePath` to be `$imagePath = "\\web01\rep-pics\$($user).png"`